# Best way to move Exim4 and vExim onto a new server

Tags: exim

What is the best way to move Exim4 with vexim to a new server?

Do you have any suggestions or experience on how to move them?

Thanks in advance!

Sebastian

Comment: Hrm, I think you should be a little bit more specific about what you actually want : do you want to migrate from a system to another with minimal (or no) downtime ? Can you describe your actual setup and what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty general since you don't give enough details of your implimentation to really be specific.

1. Get the new server up and operational including all users and mail configs.
2. Test by sending mail from a machine with /etc/host records to override DNS and point to the new server
3. When it all works, change DNS to point to the new server
4. Turn off services on the old machine and make sure queues are flushed
5. Copy user data / spools from the old to the new server.